# ef core System.ArgumentException when trying to run migration commands

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, .net-core

I am trying to use new ef core migration command `Add-Migration name` through package manager console and I'm getting:

> Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: connectionString

the full model is like this:

```
public class Blog
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class BloggingContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(Config.ConnectionString);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>().HasKey(b => b.Id);
    }
}
```

also I`m using sql server 2016 installed as database engine.

Comment: Are you sure you have a good default project selected in PMC? You can specify it explicitly (with parameter `-StartUpProjectName YOUR_PROJECT_NAME`) or select it in top-right corner of PMC

Comment: yes, there is only one simple console app. (which is set as default project)

Comment: Might be worth [submitting an issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/new).

Comment: @bricelam actually i solved the issue a while after posting this question, the problem came out to be so wired. in connection string i used "." to indicate current machine when i replaced that with the actual ip "127.0.0.1" it worked just fine.